# Convert PDF to images with page range

Tags: java, pdf

I want to know if there is a way that we can convert PDF to images by specifying a specific page range. I have tried pdfbox but I am not being able to set the resolution. Looks like it takes the default resolution of 96. I want to be able to convert PDF to jpegs of size 200*200 and 600*600 in my project. I also tried JPedal but I am not being able to find out how to specify the page range. I am only looking at Java libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an active support forum for JPedal at https://support.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/

Java creates a BufferedImage which you can then save as an image (png, jpeg, tiff). There is an example built-into JPedal showing how to convert pages to images at https://support.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/tutorials/convert-images/convert-pdf-to-bufferedimage with a link to the source code. This contains comments on scaling and you can alter the page range.

You will only be able to get 200x200 if the PDF is square if you want to preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: i read the link but could not find references to how one can give a page range...

Comment: Just found that we can use PDFDecoder.getPageAsImage(int page) to get a single page of PDF as BufferedImage and then scale it accordingly. Thank you! This solved the problem!